# Guitar training issues

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, practice

I am an amateur having some issues with my guitar playing practice. I am not sure if my question is appropriate, but I can't make it shorter for now, because the issues I am talking about might intersect somewhere.

These are my issues:

- I find it awkward to play with right and left hand from
  time to time. Could anyone recommend some good posture tutorial? If someone had similar problems, I'd like to listen about the solution.
- When I am practicing playing with metronome, repetition becomes very
  boring even after 10 minutes, especially when I am trying to play
  slower. Is there a better method to train with it? I've read about using
  background melody and I'll give it a try. Should I give a try to Guitar Pro too? It has a slow-down mode, but I think it distorts the melody a bit.
- When I am using electric guitar, I can't find the proper tuning and I am never happy with its sound. Should I play with current sound for now, or should I watch some tutorials about basics of tuning? It would be nice if someone will recommend these.

Each time I train I become very irritated by these problems. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: A session with a tutor would solve all of these problems.

Comment: What exactly is the first problem? Play with right and left hand from time time? That you play left handed and then right handed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm just getting started learning guitar, so please feel free to take my answer with a pinch of salt. I've tried learing guitar many times but always end up giving up due to the lack of progress I appeared to be making. My recommendation is to simply stick with it. Yes it will get boring at times, yes you will get irritated, but the only way is to battle through until it starts to 'click'.

For me it was finding the [Justin Sandercoe tutorials](http://www.justinguitar.com/) that convinced me to have another go, his recommendation is to practice a little but often. 4 or 5 15 minute practice sessions a week are far more enjoyable than a single hour session at the end of the week. Honestly it's far less frustrating if you can work out a simple practice routine for yourself. I find 10-15 minutes every day once I get home from work far easier to fit into my life than playing till my fingers bleed at the weekend. :-)

> I find it awkward to play with right and left hand from time to time. Could anyone recommend some good posture tutorial?

http://www.justinguitar.com/en/BC-106-PostureFingerPlacement.php

Justin provides some good posture advice here. :-)

> When I am practicing playing with metronome, repetition becomes very boring even after 10 minutes, especially when I am trying to play
>   slower. Is there a better method to train with it? I've read about
>   using background melody and I'll give it a try. Should I give a try to
>   Guitar Pro too? It has a slow-down mode, but I think it distorts the
>   melody a bit.

Then don't practice for 10 minutes. Again, Justin recommends some 1 minute practice sessions on his site. If you feel up to it, you can do loads of 1 minute sessions in one sitting, but if all you can handle is 1 or 2, then there's nothing wrong with that. This is meant to be fun, right? :-)

> When I am using electric guitar, I can't find the proper tuning and I am never happy with its sound. Should I play with current sound
>   for now, or should I watch some tutorials about basics of tuning? It
>   would be nice if someone will recommend these.

I personally practice on my Strat unplugged, firstly bacause it would irritate the missus if I cranked my amp up too much, and secondly bacause I don't want to be distracted and spend hours getting the right sound for a 15 minute practice session.

As for tuning your guitar, get a cheap tuner. It's one of the best investments you can get. I've a small clip on tuner that lives on my guitar, it only cont me about £10. I check the tuning every time I pick iup the guitar. As you get more confident you'll learn how to tune by ear, but I always double check with the tuner just in case.

> Each time I train I become very irritated by these problems. Thanks
>   for any advice.

Stick at it, the irritation will disappear as things start to work for you. Rushing isn't going to help you one little bit. You will get better with time, honest. :-)

Best of luck.

Comment: You can get clip-on tuners for pennies. Take away the guesswork. Also little and often works better, and if you're really struggling on one particular day going away and do something else for a while, but make sure you come back that same day

Answer (score 1):

> When I am practicing playing with metronome, repetition becomes very boring even after 10 minutes, especially when I am trying to play slower.

What exactly do you mean by *repetitive* ? A metronome is to help you keep the tempo steady. Whether practice is repetitive depends on the song/exercise you are practicing. The tempo doesn't have to do with a 'repetitive' practice.

> Is there a better method to train with it?

You can use a drum machine (actual or virtual). This is a way to program drums. Instead of using a metronome which can be boring, practicing with drums is much more fun. You can also use programs like Guitar Pro or Band in a Box where you can write some chords to accompany you, and that is pretty helpful and fun as well.

Αnother thing to try would be to get a looper pedal and play the accompaniment yourself on the loop and then play on top of your own recording. This wouldn't be easy for a beginner, but it'd really interesting as you develop your playing technique.

> When I am using electric guitar, I can't find the proper tuning and I am never happy with its sound.

These are two different things. First, let's talk about the tuning. There is always the standard tuning (EADGBE) and many guitarists tune to this. There are numerous alternative tunings that you can try and see which one you like best. You can google many of these tunings.

Now let's talk about the sound. The sound of the guitar itself might not be that good or it might not be to your taste. The same goes for your amp. You can also try some sounds with a pedalboard. There are pedalboards with many different sounds that can give you something you like.

> Should I play with current sound for now

You can stick with that sound for now, until you find something else you like and then switch to that.

> or should I watch some tutorials about basics of tuning?

You can watch some basic tutorials on how to tune to the standard tuning and then you can try alternative ones. These kind of tutorials will help a beginner.